# Actualizar dos campos con información de otra tabla usando ids de una tercera que las relaciona

Tags: sql, oracle, update

Necesito actualizar en **ORACLE** dos campos (`NOMBRE` y `DESCRIPCION`) de una tabla (`H_CONTROLES`) que contiene información llamada controles, con valores que están en otra tabla (`S_TRADUCCIONES`), utilizando una tercera (`M_CONTROLES`) que contiene los **id's** que relacionan las tablas.

***IMPORTANTE:*** Ni la BBDD, ni las tablas las he creado yo, sólo tengo que realizar una actualización de esos campos ya que es una tarea de mantenimiento.

La estructura de las tablas es la siguiente:

> **`S_TRADUCCIONES`**

```
ID_TRADUCCION   | TRADUCCION    | IDIOMA  |
-------------------------------------------
 10             | Control 1     | es      |
 11             | Control 2     | es      |
 12             | Control 3     | es      |
 24             | Descripcion 1 | es      |
 25             | Descripcion 2 | es      |
 26             | Descripcion 3 | es      |
 ...            | ...           | ...     |
```

> **`M_CONTROLES`**

```
ID_CONTROL  | TRD_NOMBRE    | TRD_DESCRIPCION   |
-------------------------------------------------
 1416       |   10          | 24                |
 1417       |   11          | 25                |
 1418       |   12          | 26                |
 ...        |   ...         | ...               |
```

> **`H_CONTROLES`**

```
 FK_MCONTROL    | NOMBRE    | DESCRIPCION   |
---------------------------------------------
 1416           | NULL      | NULL          | 
 1417           | NULL      | NULL          |
 1418           | NULL      | NULL          |
 ...            | ...       | ...           |
```

- **S_TRADUCCIONES**: contiene todos los textos (campo **`TRADUCCION`**) identificados por el campo **`ID_TRADUCCION`**. El campo **`IDIOMA`** identifica el idioma para la traducción, pero en este caso es irrelevante puesto que siempre filtro por idioma español ('es').
- **M_CONTROLES**: tabla maestra que contiene todos los controles, identificados por el campo **`ID_CONTROL`**, y cuyos campos **`TRD_NOMBRE`** y **`TRD_DESCRIPCION`** contienen los identificadores de las traducciones correspondientes de nombres y descripciones de los controles
- **H_CONTROLES**: tabla que contiene un histórico de controles, identificados por el campo **`FK_MCONTROL`** que corresponde con el **`ID_CONTROL`** de la tabla maestra **`M_CONTROLES`**, y los campos **`NOMBRE`** Y **`DESCRIPCION`** que necesito actualizar con los textos del campo **`TRADUCCION`** de **`S_TRADUCCIONES`**

**El resultado esperado:**

> **`H_CONTROLES`**

```
 FK_MCONTROL    | NOMBRE    | DESCRIPCION   |
---------------------------------------------
 1416           | Control 1 | Descripcion 1 | 
 1417           | Control 2 | Descripcion 2 | 
 1418           | Control 3 | Descripcion 3 | 
 ...            | ...       | ...           |
```

He utilizado subquerys para obtener las traducciones pero no consigo saber cómo podría, una vez obtenidas las traducciones, actualizar los campos `NOMBRE` y `DESCRIPCION` con diferentes valores según su `FK_MCONTROL` (`ID_CONTROL`):

```
UPDATE H_CONTROLES
SET (NOMBRE, DESCRIPCION) = (SELECT TRD_NOMBRE, TRD_DESCRIPCION FROM (
  SELECT 
    FK_MCONTROL, 
  ( SELECT TRADUCCION FROM S_TRADUCCIONES WHERE ID_IDIOMA = 'es' and ID_TRADUCCION = (
    SELECT TRD_NOMBRE FROM M_CONTROLES WHERE ID_CONTROL = X.FK_MCONTROL)) AS TRD_NOMBRE,
  ( SELECT TRADUCCION FROM S_TRADUCCIONES WHERE ID_IDIOMA = 'es' AND ID_TRADUCCION = (
    SELECT TRD_DESCRIPCION FROM M_CONTROLES WHERE ID_CONTROL = X.FK_MCONTROL)) AS TRD_DESCRIPCION
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT FK_MCONTROL FROM H_CONTROLES) X
)
```

En este punto me quedo bloqueado. No se si utilizar una cláusula del tipo `WHERE FK_MCONTROL = algo`.

También había pensando en hacer algo del tipo: (en este caso dejo sólo actualización de la columna `NOMBRE` para que se vea más claro)

```
UPDATE H_CONTROLES H 
SET NOMBRE = (SELECT TRD_NOMBRE FROM (
  SELECT
  FK_MCONTROL,
  ( SELECT TRADUCCION FROM S_TRADUCCIONES WHERE ID_IDIOMA = 'es' and ID_TRADUCCION = (
    SELECT TRD_NOMBRE FROM M_CONTROLES WHERE ID_CONTROL = X.FK_MCONTROL)) AS TRD_NOMBRE
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT FK_MCONTROL FROM H_CONTROLES) X
    ) M 
    WHERE H.FK_MCONTROL = M.FK_MCONTROL)
```

Pero no se si es lo correcto, si está bien, o es la forma más óptima de hacerlo. La verdad es que estoy algo confundido.

Comment: Si este es un caso unico de actualizacion, no importa si es optimo o  no, lo importante es que lo haga. En los casos que probaste, tuviste errores? o no se hizo como querias?

Comment: En el primer caso me da da error: `la subconsulta de una sola fila devuelve más de una fila`. En el segundo caso, tarda muchisimo, y el developer en algunos casos se me queda pillado. Pero he conseguido que funcione con la segunda opción eliminando los `FK_MCONTROL` nulos. @gbianchi

Comment: Entonces ya la resolviste? a veces es mas facil recrear la tabla con los nuevos valores directamente ;)

Comment: Sí, simplemente usé la segunda opción y añadí en el filtro `WHERE H.FK_MCONTROL = M.FK_MCONTROL AND H.FK_MCONTROL IS NOT NULL`. Al final terminó la consulta mucho más rápido. La verdad es que no había caído en recrear la tabla pero hubiera sido mucho más facil. Gracias! @gbianchi

Comment: de nada.. si la pregunta tiene una respuesta, agregala como respuesta... si no, elimina la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añado la solución que encontré por si a alguien le sirve. Es como la segunda query de la pregunta, pero añadiendo el campo que falta.
Como tardaba demasiado tiempo, filtre los registros discriminando aquellos con `FK_MCONTROl` a nulo.

```
UPDATE H_CONTROLES H 
SET (NOMBRE, DESCRIPCION) = (SELECT TRD_NOMBRE, TRD_DESCRIPCION FROM (
  SELECT
  FK_MCONTROL,
  ( SELECT TRADUCCION FROM S_TRADUCCIONES WHERE ID_IDIOMA = 'es' and ID_TRADUCCION = (
    SELECT TRD_NOMBRE FROM M_CONTROLES WHERE ID_CONTROL = X.FK_MCONTROL)) AS TRD_NOMBRE,
  ( SELECT TRADUCCION FROM S_TRADUCCIONES WHERE ID_IDIOMA = 'es' and ID_TRADUCCION = (
    SELECT TRD_DESCRIPCION FROM M_CONTROLES WHERE ID_CONTROL = X.FK_MCONTROL)) AS TRD_DESCRIPCION
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT FK_MCONTROL FROM H_CONTROLES) X
    ) M 
  WHERE H.FK_MCONTROL = M.FK_MCONTROL AND (H.FK_MCONTROL IS NOT NULL));
```